# Display table row

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-table

I want to display a table row with its button only if my condition is meet 
(e.g.: `if ($row->Estado=='Aceptado')`).

**Code:**

```
<?php
if ($cotizaciones!= FALSE) {?>  
<table id="verlistacli" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id Cotizacion</th>
        <th>Fecha Cotizacion</th>
        <th>Tipo Trabajo</th>
        <th>Origen del Material</th>
        <th>Material</th>
        <th>Dimensiones</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
    foreach ($cotizaciones->result() as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo"<td>".$row->IdCotizacion."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row->FechaCotizacion."</td>";
            if ($row->TipoTrabajo==0) {
                echo "<td>Fabricacion</td>";
            }else{
                echo "<td>Reparacion</td>";
            };
            if ($row->OrigenMaterial==0) {
                echo "<td>Empresa</td>";
            }else{
                echo "<td>Cliente</td>";
            };
            echo "<td>".$row->Material."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row->Alto."x".$row->Ancho."x".$row->Largo."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row->Cantidad."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row->Estado."</td>";
            if ($row->Estado=='Aceptado'){
    <td><a class='btn-sm btn-info' href="<?php  echo base_url('profile/detallecotizacioncli/'.$row->IdCotizacion); ?>">Detalles</a></td> 

        }?>
        <?php echo "</tr>";
    }
 ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Volver" 
 onclick="history.back(-1)" />
 <?php }else{
        echo "<h2> No hay cotizaciones <h2>";
    }?>
```

When the condition `if ($row->Estado=='Aceptado')` is meet, it returns a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please close php before html.you cant open php tag inside php tag thatswhy its showing syntax error.

**Example**

```
if ($row->Estado=='Aceptado'){ ?> <!--here you need to close php tag -->
    <td><a class='btn-sm btn-info' href="<?php  echo base_url('profile/detallecotizacioncli/'.$row->IdCotizacion); ?>">Detalles</a></td> 

    <?php } ?>
```